# Does this type of equation have a name $b^x+b^y=x^b+y^b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I was "randomly" suggested the video ["Grapesでいろんな二次グラフを描いてみた"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieVlQVtjalY), on the Hi Shibacchi YouTube channel, of various graphs. Japanese text and frantic synth music were in the background. Eventually, it came to a set of equations of the form $$b^x+b^y=x^b+y^b$$ for some constant b. I would like to know if this type of equation has a name. I put it in Desmos and played around with the sliders and it has some neat properties.

If b is even then the equation forms two curves, one of which is closed. But if it's odd, the equation forms only one curve -which is closed. There is also symmetry along the line y=x.

Edit:
After looking at it some more I found that for some reason b=2 is unique, in that it seems to be the only even number for which the closed curve doesn't contain the origin. Also, 1 and 3 are interesting. 1 doesn't contain a closed curve; additionally, for all the other odd numbers the closed curve crosses both the x and y axes at b, except for 3, which has no real roots.

Edit2:

Implicit differentiation with respect to b yields:
$$xb^{x-1}+yb^{y-1}=ln(x)x^b+ln(y)y^b$$
Which when graphed is similar for all N > 3, it consists of two curves, starting and ending on the y and x axis, respectively. It's really cool when b = 3, or less! I'm not sure what the mathematical terminology is, but the two curves "pinch" together. At b = 2 the equation seems to be inconsistent for all x and y. And at b = 1 there is only one curve!

Comment: If $x=y=0$, then the equation reduces to $2=0$, which is obviously wrong, regardless of the value of $b$, as long as $b>0$.

Comment: When I saw your title question about the equation, I said to myself what a coincidence. I watched this video yesterday too! :))

Comment: haha I also had this video recommended to me 1 or 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a
mixed exponential-polynomial
equation.